# Can we RDP a server via NIC2 when NIC1 is connected to production

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, network-adapter

I have a CCTV workstation (Dell 7920 workstation with multiple NICs). The way it is planned is to connect NIC1 to production environment.
Can i configure NIC2 with IP on different segment and do a RDP to the CCTV workstation via NIC2 and use it to configure and manage?
Is this possible?

Note: Both NIC1 and NNNIC2 will have different gateways. Does leaving NIC2 gateway blank help in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is not only possible but also straight forward.

- Configure the NIC as wanted
- Make sure, you have connectivity (e.g. Ping) between the CCTV workstation and your target RDP client
- Make sure, the Windows Firewall allows RDP on the secondary NIC

Works fine, I use it quite often.

Comment: Hi. thanks for reply. But if NIC1 and NIC2 have its own gateway? WIll it create problem?

Comment: It shouldn't. If it really does (Windows has only very basic routing features), you can try putting this gateway first in the list.